# Run MsBuild.Coverlet without dotnet command

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, cobertura, coverlet

I have an old project (VS2105) I'm unable to use the `dotnet` command so I'm trying to use `coverlet.msbuild` task.

`MSBuild.exe my-solution.sln /t:My_Project_Test:InstrumentModules /t:My_Project_Test:GenerateCoverageResult /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:Include="[*]*"`

But it returns zero data

```
Calculating coverage result...
  Generating report 'C:\Users\MyProject\My.Project.Tests\coverage.json'

+---------------------------+------+--------+--------+
| Module                    | Line | Branch | Method |
+---------------------------+------+--------+--------+
| My.Project| 0%   | 0%     | 0%     |
+---------------------------+------+--------+--------+

+---------+------+--------+--------+
|         | Line | Branch | Method |
+---------+------+--------+--------+
| Total   | 0%   | 0%     | 0%     |
+---------+------+--------+--------+
| Average | 0%   | 0%     | 0%     |
+---------+------+--------+--------+
```

I'm currently using

Net Framework 4.6.1
xunit.runner.msbuild 2.4.1
coverlet.msbuild 2.9.0
ReportGenerator 4.8.13

This is the content of the My.Project.Test.csprj

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\ReportGenerator.4.8.13\build\netstandard2.0\ReportGenerator.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\ReportGenerator.4.8.13\build\netstandard2.0\ReportGenerator.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.2.9.0\build\coverlet.msbuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.2.9.0\build\coverlet.msbuild.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\xunit.runner.msbuild.2.4.1\build\net452\xunit.runner.msbuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\xunit.runner.msbuild.2.4.1\build\net452\xunit.runner.msbuild.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.3.1\build\xunit.runner.console.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.3.1\build\xunit.runner.console.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.3.1\build\net20\xunit.runner.visualstudio.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.3.1\build\net20\xunit.runner.visualstudio.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{DBDBC567-2968-41A5-A6D0-A55F4EA89927}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>My.Project.Tests</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>My.Project.Tests</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Castle.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Castle.Core.4.2.0\lib\net45\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NSubstitute, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92dd2e9066daa5ca, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NSubstitute.3.1.0\lib\net46\NSubstitute.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.3.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="xunit.abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\xunit.abstractions.2.0.1\lib\net35\xunit.abstractions.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="xunit.assert, Version=2.2.0.3545, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\xunit.assert.2.2.0\lib\netstandard1.1\xunit.assert.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="xunit.core, Version=2.2.0.3545, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\xunit.extensibility.core.2.2.0\lib\netstandard1.1\xunit.core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="xunit.execution.desktop, Version=2.2.0.3545, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\xunit.extensibility.execution.2.2.0\lib\net452\xunit.execution.desktop.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="GeolocationFacts.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SeoFriendlyPageNameFacts.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ShortTermFacts.cs" />
    <Compile Include="StateExtractorFacts.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\My.Project\My.Project.csproj">
      <Project>{449e7e30-0626-471e-9740-a03614494425}</Project>
      <Name>My.Project</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{82A7F48D-3B50-4B1E-B82E-3ADA8210C358}" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.3.1\build\net20\xunit.runner.visualstudio.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.3.1\build\net20\xunit.runner.visualstudio.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.3.1\build\xunit.runner.console.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.3.1\build\xunit.runner.console.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\xunit.runner.msbuild.2.4.1\build\net452\xunit.runner.msbuild.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\xunit.runner.msbuild.2.4.1\build\net452\xunit.runner.msbuild.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\xunit.runner.msbuild.2.4.1\build\net452\xunit.runner.msbuild.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\xunit.runner.msbuild.2.4.1\build\net452\xunit.runner.msbuild.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.2.9.0\build\coverlet.msbuild.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.2.9.0\build\coverlet.msbuild.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.2.9.0\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.2.9.0\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\ReportGenerator.4.8.13\build\netstandard2.0\ReportGenerator.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\ReportGenerator.4.8.13\build\netstandard2.0\ReportGenerator.props'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\xunit.runner.msbuild.2.4.1\build\net452\xunit.runner.msbuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\xunit.runner.msbuild.2.4.1\build\net452\xunit.runner.msbuild.targets')" />
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <TestAssemblies Include="**\bin\Release\*.Tests.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="Rebuild">
    <xunit Assemblies="@(TestAssemblies)" />
  </Target>
  
  <Import Project="..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.2.9.0\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\coverlet.msbuild.2.9.0\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets')" />
  
  
</Project>
```

Comment: From the result(command line) you shown, it seems there was no error appear, are you sure that your test has codes covered? Besides, try this command: `MSBuild.exe my_project_test.csproj /t:InstrumentModules /t:GenerateCoverageResult …`(first type `cd your_test_project_directory` and then type this command, you may need to provide the absolute path of MSBuild.exe)

Comment: I tested like this: type `cd C:\MySolution_folder\MyTestProject_folder`, type `"C:\Program Files (x86)\....\MSBuild.exe" MyTestProjectName.csproj /t:InstrumentModules /t:GenerateCoverageResult /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputForm=cobertura`

Comment: Hi Tianyu, I tried this way, but again it returns zero results, could you please tell me which version of coverlet.msbuild are you using. Thanks

Comment: Symon, I am using coverlet.msbuild 2.9.0. I think it's the same version of which you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `IncludeTestAssembly` property to work:

```
MSBuild.exe my-solution.sln /t:My_Project_Test:InstrumentModules /t:My_Project_Test:GenerateCoverageResult /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:Include="[*]*" /p:IncludeTestAssembly=true
```

You could also use the command that [Tianyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16363677/tianyu) provide.

Comment: Thanks it works now